# What is it called when a font's character(s) changes form based on the sequence of letters surrounding it?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

What is it called when a font's character(s) changes form based on the sequence of letters surrounding it?

Consider the character `o` and the sequence of characters `oo`.

Expected result:
[image: expected result]

Actual result:
[image: actual result]

Comment: Do you mean ligature?

Comment: @Noah, I don't think so... the `oo` isn't counted as 1 character.

Comment: @Noah, after further reading, I am compelled to say you found the right term. I was looking for a ligature table. Thank you.

Comment: Ligatures are the simplest form of contextual shaping. For languages such as Arabic, much more extensive contextual shaping is required.

Comment: @PaulDempsey Why is more contextual shaping required for Arabic, and what might that look like?

Comment: Because in Arabic script there are more factors than simple character adjacency that determines the shape of the glyph.